# Recommended Books for Multi Core Processors

Tags: multicore

I need to write an essay on multi-core processing, are there any good books for recommendation? thanks! :)

Comment: Is this a comparison between AMD and Intel, or is it wider, including e.g. Sun Niagra, IBM Power series, and GPUs? You'll likely find reasonable articles on the web.

Comment: is probably not comparisons, its more on what is multi core processing and what are the downs and ups bla bla bla. i just thought maybe a book can aid in my understanding before proceeding with this paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Computer Architecture: A Quantitative Approach](http://mkp.com/news/computer-architecture-5th-edition-a-quantitative-approach-by-john-l-hennessy-david-a-patterson), 5th Edition by John L. Hennessy & David A. Patterson or [Computer Architecture: A Quantitative Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123704901) 4th Edition

covers things at a high level, and might be in a library nearby.

Also [Computer Organization and Design, Revised Fourth Edition, Fourth Edition: The Hardware/Software Interface](http://textbooks.elsevier.com/web/product_details.aspx?isbn=9780123747501) by the same authors.

But [Wikipedia Multi-core](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor) processor would get you started with lots of references.

[Multicore Processors – A Necessity](http://www.csa.com/discoveryguides/multicore/review.pdf) looked like a relatively straightforward starting point.